# How to read the .log output of ConEmu console in Windows

Tags: ubuntu, logging, windows-subsystem-for-linux, conemu

I am using ConEmu to run Ubuntu consoles in Windows 10. I have specified that ConEmu exports .log files automatically at the end of each session. The log files look like this in Sublime Text:

[image: Sublime Text Screenshot]

There is a lot of ASCII codes such as <0x1b>.

Opening with Notepad looks like this:

[image: Notepad screenshots]

Which is a bit clearer but still not easy to understand.

Is there another program in Windows that could read these log files correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You may use `sed` to trim all ANSI sequences and after that view them in any editors.

Or you may print the log file in ConEmu or any other terminal and browse the session there.